# Java8 string deduplication and jruby - no effect?

Tags: java, jruby

I'm experimenting with java8 string deduplication and sadly I'm unable to create a jruby program which can demonstrate how enabling java deduplication also helps jruby (1.7.19).

Questions:

- Does jruby take advantage of java8 string deduplication? Is there a special option for jruby for this?
- Is there an example program to show how jruby running with `-J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication` is better than jruby without this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JRuby's (Ruby) String (instances of `org.jruby.RubyString`) objects are different from `java.lang.String` ... thus the deduplication won't have effect on your Ruby Strings. The internal representation of `org.jruby.util.ByteList` (Ruby String internals) is `byte[]` while the de-duplication works on `char[]` arrays (internals of a Java String).

there's no special flag for this on JRuby, it still might have some effect since String instances (although mostly interned e.g. for Ruby method names) are used internally - how much it's hard to tell without trying (but if it's actually much it might be considered a bug).